# Как можно удалить конкретный элемент при клике на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

Есть вот такая табличка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И ее код

```
<table id={'tableH'} className="history__body">
    {
      this.props.room?.discussions.map((d) => d.end != null && (
        // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-key
        <div className={'history__story__body'}>
          <Story discussionId={d.id} onClick={this.handleClickOpen} key={d.id} title={d.title} average={d.averageVote} />
          <Button onClick={undefined} className={'history__story-btnDelete'} title={<img src={remove} />} />
        </div>
      ))
    }
  </table>
```

```
const Story: React.FC<IProps> = (props) => {
  return <div onClick={() => props.onClick(props.discussionId)}>
    <tr className="history__story">
      <td>{props.title}</td>
      <td className="history__story-value">{props.average}</td>
    </tr>
  </div>
    ;
}
```

И такие story вместе с кнопкой справа от нее добавляются в эту табличку.
Так вот как удалить всю конкретную строчку при клике на кнопку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Поставьте `key` для `history__story__body` и уберите `// eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-key`. Будет что-то вроде `key="d.id"`
2. Нужно написать функции ВМЕСТО `onClick={undefined}`. Что это будет за функции, уже зависит от того, ОТКУДА вы берёте данные в пропсах `props.room.discussions`. Т.е. ТАМ где формируются данные. Скорее всего, нужно сделать запрос на сервер. И потом только удалять
3. После ответа от сервера, или если нужно только локально (без запроса на сервер), меняете стейт, НЕ мутируя данные. Как-то так https://jsfiddle.net/e3try762/

Comment: спасибо за наводку, все заработало как надо с первой попытки(я в шоке когда работает что-то с первого раза) Я примерно так и сделал, на сервер сделал запрос, на сервере удалил discussion и по сути все. `<Button onClick={() => this.props.onClick(discussion.id)} />`

Answer (score 0):

Это простой пример как надо удалять строку из таблицы, надеюсь вам будет полезно:

```js
const {useState} = React;

function Row({company, remove}) {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{company.name}</td>
      <td>{company.contact}</td>
      <td><button onClick={remove}>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
  )
}

function Table({companies, setCompanies}) {
  
  const removeCompany = (index) => {
    setCompanies(companies.filter((company, i) => i !== index));
  }
  
  return (
     <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
      {companies.map((item, index) => <Row company={companies[index]} remove={() => removeCompany(index)}/>)}
    </table> 
  )
}

function App() {
  const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([
    {
      name: 'Company 1',
      contact: 'Company 1 contact'
    },
    {
      name: 'Company 2',
      contact: 'Company 2 contact'
    },
    {
      name: 'Company 3',
      contact: 'Company 3 contact'
    },
    {
      name: 'Company 4',
      contact: 'Company 4 contact'
    },
    {
      name: 'Company 5',
      contact: 'Company 5 contact'
    },
  ]);
  
  return (
    <Table companies={companies} setCompanies={setCompanies}/>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: нет. так делать не нужно! Вы "мутируете" данные (массив)

Comment: @ЮрийКопоть Извините меня, конечно, но чего вы ожидали? Чтобы я здесь создал сервер и всё делал через запросы? Это просто, простой пример, а не код для продакшена

Comment: вы не поняли. Вы неправильно удаляете данные из стейта. вы его мутируете. Сервер тут не при чем!

Comment: @ЮрийКопоть Я бы мутировал, если бы писал `data = ...;` и потом `satData(data)`, а я именно вставляю новый стейт делая `setData(...data)`

Comment: Посмотрите как работает splice. И вот вам пример https://jsfiddle.net/xqtv4f3p/ (Ваш код, и нужный стейт НЕ обновляю)

Comment: @ЮрийКопоть Я знаю как работает splice. Как раз таки у вас происходит работа с мутацией, т.к. вы не обновляете стейт, а я изменённый массив вставляю как новый стейт

Comment: splice как раз мутирует данные ))) и в пример я вам показал. Или вы думаете, что если вы написали setState, то данные не мутируется ?  ). Вы ДО того, как вставить данные в стейт, УЖЕ его мутировали

Comment: @ЮрийКопоть Вы не поняли меня, я знаю что splice на месте изменяет массив. Я могу делать с этим массивом что захочу, изменять, удалять, но в стейт я должен положить каждый раз новый массив c нужными значениями

Comment: судя по всему, вы не до конца понимаете, что значит не мутировать данные. Ещё раз: применив splice, вы УЖЕ изменили стейт. А сделав setState, вы просто запустили рендер. А по данным, вы изменили массив, и ТАКОЙЖЕ массив (уже изменённый) положили в стейт. Не делайте так, это выстрел себе в ногу. В будущем вы столкнётесь с трудностями с таким подходом

Comment: И вот вам последний пример. https://jsfiddle.net/xqtv4f3p/1/ Я специально, добавил задержку для setState

Comment: @ЮрийКопоть Ладно, я с вами согласен, так делать нельзя) Сонный и злой был, не хотел видеть ошибку. Извините! Исправился)